# Image not showing in imageView if I used circular image

Tags: ios, layout, uiimageview, layer, cornerradius

I have a table view and I need to show author_img in section header. In ViewForSectionHeader method, I want to make the image to be circular. But If I did that, the images are not showing at all, no matter in simulator or in real device. If I remove the code, uiimageview will show the images normally. I set up the width and height constraint for uiimageview because I want to get fixed size of showing images. So Any ideas, please?

```
    cell.author_img.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.author_img.frame.size.width/2
    cell.author_img.layer.masksToBounds = true
    //  add a boundary for thumb
    cell.author_img.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    cell.author_img.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Comment: Use cell.author_img.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya added, but still not working

Comment: Show me your method code and UI thats will appear in simulator

Comment: @user3162215 : Which xcode version are you using? Give the code you are used for assigning the image to imageView.

Comment: @user3162215 check my answer your problem solve easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may come from the fact that you are setting the cornerRadius too early, the final size of your `author_img` is not fixed yet. 
Try to set that cornerRadius when you are sure that the layout of your cell has been entirely calculated.

For test purpose, just to make sure it is coming from this behaviour, try to hardcode the cornerRadius.

```
cell.author_img.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

If your image has a slight cornerRadius, it means that the issue is coming from what I explained earlier, if it is still not showing, it is coming from something else.

If it does come from the fact the size of your image is not fixed, try to set your cornerRadius in something like `viewDidAppear`, I mean the latest you can do.

Comment: Ok cool :) the thing with hardcoded cornerRadius is that it won't be dynamic, if the size of your header changes, you will end up with a non rounded image :/ the way you did (by setting the size with half the width of the image it self is the way to do it dynamically, but you'll need to put that code in a place where the header layout won't change anymore).

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 210/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let iconimage: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 40, 40))
        iconimage.image = UIImage(named: "original.jpg")
        iconimage.layer.cornerRadius = iconimage.frame.size.height / 2
        iconimage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        iconimage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        iconimage.clipsToBounds = true

        let subjectNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 4, width: 250, height: 35))
        subjectNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        subjectNameLabel.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
        subjectNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        headerView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        if isFristtime == true {
            let subjectNameTxtValue = "Mile Ho Tum Humko"
             subjectNameLabel.text = subjectNameTxtValue
        }else{
            let subjectNameTxtValue = "Saiyaan"
             subjectNameLabel.text = subjectNameTxtValue
        }




        subjectNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 210/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
          headerView.addSubview(iconimage)
        headerView.addSubview(subjectNameLabel)

        return headerView
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
```

[image]

Comment: @user3162215 if you want to increase image hight then simply increase your header size and in init time give hight like frame.size.hight and width give frame.size.hight so its work fine for you and its display a big image in header