# iOS8 image not showing in round corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

[image]

I'm trying to make corners of image as round but its not showing round image. Please suggest me.

```
 self.Image.layer.cornerRadius = self.Image.frame.size.width / 2;
 self.Image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
 self.Image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
 self.Image.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
```

Comment: Are you working with autolayout?

Comment: yes i am using autolayout.

Comment: you are put your current screen shot ? which type image display?

Comment: self.Image.layer.masksToBounds = YES; replace this line with self.Image.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: Then you need to set the rounded corner in layoutSubviews or didLayoutSubViews

Comment: also have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39889098/4662531 it maybe related ;)

Comment: ok i use this its showing same i also try this .

Comment: I tried your code. Its working with auto Layout. You should post a screenshot of current image. Also where are you adding your code ?

Comment: @viveksharma you should mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working perfectly. Image view is rounded. See the corners are rounded.Actually, The image you are using is a "Landscape". Try using some another image. or change `imageView's` "Mode" property to `scale to fill`. You will get the results.

```
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Use this code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must make sure the `image.size.width` is equal to `image.size.height`.

```
self.Image.layer.cornerRadius = self.Image.frame.size.width /2;
 self.Image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

the first condition is to ensure that the picture is a square, then the above code can cut picture into a circular.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your question's state?