# uiimageview corner radius not working in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

`UIImageView` corner radius not working inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method
 and and i am using is prototype cell.

I also tried  **`layoutIfNeeded` method unfortunately doesn't work**.

Here is my code:

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
client_image=[cell viewWithTag:3];

[client_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[info objectForKey:PRE_USERIMAGE]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PLACE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];

// client_image=(UIImageView*)[TMGlobalFunction changebgLayer:client_image];
        ;
//  [client_image layoutIfNeeded];
client_image.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
client_image.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
client_image.layer.cornerRadius = client_image.frame.size.height/2;
client_image.layer.borderWidth=[TMGlobalFunction IsiPad]?4.0f:2.0f;
```

**This works fine when I set it manually like:**

```
client_image.layer.cornerRadius = 50;
```

**But it's not working when i upgrade *Xcode 7 to 8* with below code:**

```
client_image.layer.cornerRadius = client_image.frame.size.height/2;
```

Any idea how why i am getting this wired issue?

**Update:** *it is issue in Xcode 8 when I print `client_image.frame.size.height` it's return 1000 first time. after scrolling it's return right value.*

Comment: try to print `client_image.frame.size.height/2` let me know what you get in console ?

Comment: it's return 1000. first time after scrolling it's return right value.

Comment: so you need 500 corner radius in `client_image` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888806/image-not-showing-in-imageview-if-i-used-circular-image/39910728#39910728 see this

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya i already mention it's work if i set it manually client_image.layer.cornerRadius = 50;

Comment: what is your client_image frame size?

Comment: @balkaransingh : I think the "height" you are getting is wrong so it is not working.

Comment: Give fix width and fix Height to your ImageView. It should do the trick.

Comment: Are you calling this inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @balkaransingh brother check my whole code

Comment: @balkaransingh you don't need to write [cell layoutIfNeeded]; this line without this its work fine

Comment: @Wolverine but i need image size increase according to cell.

Comment: Then in that case you have to try it using Block. Once you cell is fully loaded and image is loaded accordingly then after you will get the proper width and height of that image. Then may be your code do the trick.

Comment: I think you are using SDWebimage, Use it's method which have parameters of Block. in SucessBlock you write this Round corner code By getting main queue.

Comment: @Wolverine it's issue with xcode 8 in xcode 7 my code work fine.

Comment: @Wolverine i am using UIImageView+AFNetworking.h not SDWebimage.

Comment: @balkaransingh just replace your code with mine one and check output .

Comment: @balkaransingh Afnetworking also have that kind method. Dig a little bit.

Comment: @balkaransingh try calling `[self layoutIfNeeded];` instead of `[cell layoutIfNeeded];` so layout method applied to overall body of app, may solves.

Comment: @Wolverine the main issue that I print client_image.frame.size.height it's return 1000 first time. after scrolling it's return right value .

Answer (score 3):

call layoutIfneed and LayoutSubviews both before using frame of Imageview. Try following..Working for me.

```html
 
client_image=[cell viewWithTag:3];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
[cell  layoutSubviews];


[client_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[info objectForKey:PRE_USERIMAGE]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PLACE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];

// client_image=(UIImageView*)[TMGlobalFunction changebgLayer:client_image];
        ;
//  [client_image layoutIfNeeded];
client_image.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
client_image.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
client_image.layer.cornerRadius = client_image.frame.size.height/2;
client_image.layer.borderWidth=[TMGlobalFunction IsiPad]?4.0f:2.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **cellForRow**, Try this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:url..."];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_placeholder"];

__weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

[cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                      placeholderImage:placeholderImage
                               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                                   weakCell.imageView.image = image;

                                   // Write your code here for Rounding corner
                                   [weakCell setNeedsLayout];

                               } failure:nil];
```

Below is the method which will return the image and you can set this in YourImageView.

Try to give round corner to YourImageView in this method's sucessblock.

**From AFNetworking Documentation :**

```
/**
 Asynchronously downloads an image from the specified URL request, and sets it once the request is finished. Any previous image request for the receiver will be cancelled.
 If the image is cached locally, the image is set immediately, otherwise the specified placeholder image will be set immediately, and then the remote image will be set once the request is finished.
 If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block to set the image of the image view before returning. If no success block is specified, the default behavior of setting the image with `self.image = image` is applied.
 @param urlRequest The URL request used for the image request.
 @param placeholderImage The image to be set initially, until the image request finishes. If `nil`, the image view will not change its image until the image request finishes.
 @param success A block to be executed when the image data task finishes successfully. This block has no return value and takes three arguments: the request sent from the client, the response received from the server, and the image created from the response data of request. If the image was returned from cache, the response parameter will be `nil`.
 @param failure A block object to be executed when the image data task finishes unsuccessfully, or that finishes successfully. This block has no return value and takes three arguments: the request sent from the client, the response received from the server, and the error object describing the network or parsing error that occurred.
 */
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure;

/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give corner radius in `willDisplayCell` of `tableView` delegate and check:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     client_image=[cell viewWithTag:3];

     [client_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[info objectForKey:PRE_USERIMAGE]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PLACE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];

     //client_image=(UIImageView*)[TMGlobalFunction changebgLayer:client_image];
        ;
     //[client_image layoutIfNeeded];
     client_image.clipsToBounds = YES;
     client_image.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
     client_image.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
     client_image.layer.cornerRadius = client_image.frame.size.height/2;
     client_image.layer.borderWidth=[TMGlobalFunction IsiPad]?4.0f:2.0f;

     [cell layoutSubviews];
     [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is related to auto layout. He mentioned that if he is setting it manually then it works.

Comment: May be that is the case@Wolverine

Comment: @RonakChaniyara it's issue with xcode 8 it's work fine in xcode 7.

Comment: Have you tried above code? may be it is issue related to autolayout as Wolverine said@balkaransingh

Comment: @RonakChaniyara i try this above code but it's not working. I print client_image.frame.size.height it's return 1000 first time. after scrolling it's return right value.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YOURCELLINDETIFIER";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   UIImageView *profile = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:90]; // your imageview tag

    profile.layer.cornerRadius = profile.frame.size.width / 2;
    profile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    profile.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    profile.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:"YOUR URL HERE"; // your URL
    [profile sd_setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (!error) {
            profile.image=image;
        }
    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i get the image right. but issue with it's cornerRadius .

Comment: update your question with your - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  { method that return your tableviewcell hight } and also update your Runtime UI

Answer (score 0):

Size of the `client_image` frame is reported incorrect thats why you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` method. Just try calling `[self layoutIfNeeded];` inside `viewDidLoad` method before doing any cornerRadius stuff.

Comment: it's not working it's work if i use image in uiviewcontroller not in cell.

Comment: i am not using any custom class for tableview cell.

Comment: but surely its a layout issue, try getting the value before passing to `cornerRadius` directly then i think 1000 is big figure, you are almost done help yourself.

Comment: @balkaransingh your issue is around here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503661/cornerradius-stopped-working-in-swift-2-3-ios-10-xcode-8 see all the ans.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

cell.previewImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.previewImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//asper your requirement give the value of radius.
```